# How to write multidimensional array in JS in a loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have the following code:

```
var marketReturns = [1];
var marketReturnsVol = [1];
var marketVolatility = [1];
var yearlyReturns = [];
var yearlyReturns2 = [];
for (y = 0; y < 50000; y++) {
    for (x = 1; x <= 251; x++) {
        do {
            var rand1 = Math.random();
            var rand2 = Math.random();
            var x1 = 2.0 * rand1 - 1.0;
            var x2 = 2.0 * rand2 - 1.0;
            var w = Math.pow(x1, 2) + Math.pow(x2, 2);
        } while (w === 0 || w > 1);
        multiplier = Math.sqrt((-2 * Math.log(w)) / w);
        var volVol = 1 + (((x2 * multiplier) / 100) * 5.98); // real ^VIX is 5.98.
        marketVolatility[x] = volVol * marketVolatility[x - 1];
        var y1 = 1 + (((x1 * multiplier) / 100) * 1.07); // 1.07 is the daily vol of ^GSPC
        var y12 = 1 + (((x1 * multiplier) / 100) * 1.07 * marketVolatility[x]) + 0.00038; // 1.07 is the daily vol of ^GSPC
        marketReturns[x] = y1 * marketReturns[x - 1];
        marketReturnsVol[x] = y12 * marketReturnsVol[x - 1];
    }
    yearlyReturns[y] = marketReturns[251];
    yearlyReturns2[y] = marketReturnsVol[251];
}
yearlyReturns.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (a - b);
})
yearlyReturns2.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (a - b);
})
for (x = 0; x < yearlyReturns.length; x++) {
    document.write(yearlyReturns2[x] + ", ");
}
```

So essentially I am calculating marketReturns, which is marketReturns[x-1] * daily change. I want however to make this into subarrays where I can preserve all the individual marketReturns for each iteration of y instead of just preserving the last day like I am in yearlyReturns[y].

I thought I could do it as such:

```
marketReturns[y][x] = y1 * marketReturns[y][x - 1];
marketReturnsVol[y][x] = y12 * marketReturnsVol[y][x - 1];
```

But this doesn't work. Is there any way for me to start writing the marketReturns figures into subarrays? Thanks.

Comment: You can make use of objects to make the code more readable and maintainable. Use arrays only where you want array operations.

Answer (score 0):

You can mimic the multidimensional array using nested array/nested object in javascript:

e.g.

```
var arr = [];

//Initialize a 10x10 "multidimensional" array
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    arr[i] = [];

    for(var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        arr[i][j] = 0;
    }
}

//Store
arr[5][5] = 10;
```

Comment: Ah so I have to initialize every subarray before trying to put variables in. Thanks!